# Method overloading related: when null is passed as a paramater

Tags: java, overloading

Can anyone explain the output of the below program when null is passed as a parameter

```
 public class TestThis {

        public void method(Object o){
            System.out.println("object method");
        }

    public void method(int[] intArray){
        System.out.println("int array method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestThis().method(null);
    }

}
```

**Output:-**
int array method

```
public class TestThis {

    public void method(Object o){
        System.out.println("object method");
    }

    public void method(int[] intArray){
        System.out.println("int array method");
    }

    public void method(double[] doubleArray){
        System.out.println("double array method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestThis().method(null);
    }

}
```

**Compile time error**:-
The method method(Object) is ambiguous for the type TestThis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method having most specific / least generic type is chosen. `Object` is the *superclass* of all other classes, so, in the first case, `int[] intArray` method is chosen.

In the second case, you have 2 types at the same level, this will cause compilation problems. You cannot have `String` and `StringBuilder` because they are at the same level in the class hierarchy. You can have `Exception`, `IOException` because they are at different levels.

`null` can be passed to any method that takes a reference type as argument, but at the same time you need to ensure that you don't have methods that take types that are at the same level.

Comment: @yeppe - `int[]` is also a class which is at a lower level than `Object` class and hence it was chosen. Class hierarchy is `Object` is at top level and all other thigns come below it right?

Comment: Assuming you meant `Double` and `Float` instead of `double` and `float` (which are primitives), yes, the least generic class will be chosen

Comment: Primitive array types, also, Object and double primitive array--> method that has double primitive array pram would be selected by the compiler and (Object <>float primitive array) --> method that has float primitive array param and so forth. { compiler picks up the more specific once.} :)

Comment: @yeppe - yes, thats right

Answer (score 1):

The compiler sees that you have **two** methods that could both take **Object** as parameter (because an array of double is an Object, too).

So, when you only pass null, the compiler can't tell which method you want to call.

What would work instead:

```
new TestThis().method((double[]) null);
```

For the record: the thing is - this is not about **polymorphism**, it is about overloading. The compiler has to **fix** which of your overloaded methods to invoke at **compile time**. Therefore the complains to you, if your source code doesn't give enough information to make that decision.

And to be precise: in your first example, there are two methods, and the compiler picks the one for (Object).

But in your second example, you got **three** methods, and two are more specific than (Object). That is why it refuses to compile example 2.

Comment: Wouldnt an int array be an object aswell?

Comment: @yeppe: No, `null` is of the [null type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1).

Comment: Edited my question. Went down the the wrong path for that aspect of the question.

Comment: "two are more specific than (Object)" There's a bit missing here: you can have two methods more specific than `Object` without ambiguous overload, e.g. if you have overloads for `Object`, `CharSequence` and `String`. Could you make this more precise?